# How to generate random 6 digit which expire after 5 second?

Tags: c#

I got a logic which generate a 6 digit number which remain constant up to 5 sec. Here is the code. The problem is the below routine generate number sequentially which I do not want rather I want dynamic that any user can not guess what will be the next number.

```
public static int GetTimestamp()
{
    // 10m ticks in a second, so 50m in 5 seconds
    const int ticksIn5Seconds = 50000000;
    return (int)((DateTime.Now.Ticks / ticksIn5Seconds) % 1000000);
}
```

Here another code which Generate Unique 8 digit Number in C#.

```
public string Get8Digits()
 {
   var bytes = new byte[4];
   var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
   rng.GetBytes(bytes);
   uint random = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0) % 100000000;
   return String.Format("{0:D8}", random);
 }
```

I try to combine both the logic to generate random 6 digit number which may not be guessed what next 6 digit number will be generated. Looking for guidance what should I do to achieve my objective. Thanks.

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. Want a random number? Call Random's Next method. Want random number every 5 seconds? Call Next every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution based on your own `Get8Digits` method...

```
    private static DateTime _expiry = DateTime.MinValue;
    private static string _current = "0";

    public string CurrentNumber()
    {
        if (_expiry < DateTime.Now)
        {
            _expiry = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
            _current = Get8Digits();
        }

        return _current;
    }
```

Comment: one request that if the same program run on multile pc then there is a change to generate same number for two pc. so can i make it userid wise. user id can be collection of digit or alpha num. so tell me how can i generate random number based on user id which will keep alive for next 5 sec?

Comment: @Thomas: Two machines have to generate the same random number in the same time interval if some user ID value given to them is the same? This considerably changes the problem. RB's solution could be updated to handle this, as long as time is synchronized on two machines, but now there is a more important question for you. What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can seed the Pseudo Random Generator with the time modulo 5 seconds (actually time - time % 5s). It would work but it's not the best way to get good unpredictive numbers.

Edit with code :

```
Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks - (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 50000000));
```

Edit2 with more code :

```
int random5 = random.Next(100000, 999999)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "random every time" ? In a 5 second time frame the seed would be the same so the random number would also be the same. But I agree with you that using only the first generated number of a PRNG is not very efficient.

Comment: This is not going to be any harder to guess to just return the datetime ticks - Random will be predictable and everyone could calculate it for given time, doesn't meet the "anyone could guess" part

Comment: I'm not returning the datetime ticks, you're supposed to use the random object to generate ONE random number as RB shows in his own answer.

Comment: I can see it's not returning the ticks - it scrambles them first, but in a predictable way - no new information other than the ticks is returned

Comment: how to get the actual number in ur case ? can u write the full code which will return number. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Stopwatch age; // init me
private static int lastRandom = 0;
public static int GetTimestamp()
{
  if (age.Elapsed.TotalSeconds>5 ||lastRandom==0){
     lastRandom = Guid.NewGuid().GetHash(); // stronger random than Random
     age.Reset();
  }
  return lastRandom % 100000; // limit the digits to 6, assuming leading 0s
}
```

Comment: I would advise against using `Guid().GetHash()` as a random generator, since that's not what it's meant for. Either use `Random`, or `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` for stronger randomness.

Comment: `Random` is not even close to being a decent random number generator, if you're advising *for* it. Cryto is used by GUID

Comment: this line giving prob lastRandom = Guid.NewGuid().GetHash(); so i use RandomNumberGenerator.Create() but the problem what will be data type of lastRandom variable ?? please modify ur code. thanks

Comment: can u use RandomNumberGenerator.Create() instead of Guid.NewGuid().GetHash(); and modify ur code accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas you can just use your `Get8Digits` and store the string. I'd advise against making a new RNG every time

Answer (score -1):

I understand your question to be that you want to generate a random number generator that will generate a different random number every 5 seconds.

```
public int GetRandomValue() 
{
    // Seed the RNG with an integer that changes every 5 seconds.
    Random rnd = new Random((int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks / ticksIn5Seconds));
    // Generate a 6 digit random number.
    return rnd.Next(100000, 999999); 
}
```

Comment: This is going to be random every time, not keeping it for 5 seconds

Comment: @StenPetrov No it's not. I've edited the answer to make it clear that we are not *reusing* the Random object, in case that wasn't obvious.

Comment: i want to generate 6 digit random number after every 5 sec but with in 5 sec the number will not be changed. am i clear?

Comment: That's pretty clear and this answer (same as mine) works well but I agree with the concerns about the randomness of the generated series...

Comment: @Thomas In that case I think you'll have to store the generated value somewhere. Will that be a problem and, if so, please explain why.

Comment: This is not a "random" number, it returns a predictable hash of the timestamp

Comment: @Thomas, this is not a good solution. The result is maybe "random" but is not unpredictable. Anyone can predict what a number will be in any given time. Dan's solution is better one. Random is calculated once and reused in 5 second interval.

Comment: @Dialecticus yes and that's the problem using only the first generated number with a predictive seed. That's what make this solution elegant but not very effective.

Comment: @RB. - This code has problems and I expect more from somebody with so much reputation. If `GetRandomValue()` was called more then one within a very short amount of time this would generate the same number. Besides just calling Random.Next every 5 seconds is enough to do what the author wants. Furthermore DateTime.Now() is an expensive (performance) operation.  The problems with this code can be resolved by using a second `Random` object.

Comment: @Ramhound The criticism about the number not being sufficiently random is valid. However, I don't think it's a valid criticism to say that calling `GetRandomValue` repeatedly would generate the same number because that was explicitly what the author had asked for (or, at least, my interpretation of his rather confusing question).